# Did Kale knock out Goku?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super episode 100,

> After Kale went all rage in super saiyajin green "berserker", and after she fired ki blasts in all directions, Goku appeared in base form after being in super saiyajin blue. Though I dont think wee see a ki blast impacting him.

Did Kale knock out Goku? or he transformed back to base form?

Answer (score 1):

He simply transformed back to base form. If he was knocked out or seriously injured he would start being a lot more serious as based on his past actions throughout dragon ball(z/super). Instead when he got back he didn't look injured at all.